# What is the impact of compiling a program in 32 bits mode regarding optimizations

Tags: c, gcc, 64-bit

What are the differences in performance introduced when compiling an application in 32 bit mode on a 64 architecture?

For example by using gcc with the `-m32` option on a machine running a 64 bit version of Linux.

Will the program be compiled with full use of SIMD instructions?

Would the average program greatly benefit of the extra registers?

Comment: Not a duplicate, but related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12224809/do-32bit-apps-run-faster-or-slower-on-a-64bit-os

Comment: Pointer operands will be half the size, so the binary is more compact, giving you better cache use and quite possibly a performance *boost*.

Comment: "a substantially reduced instruction set?" -- no; why would you think so? "a great deal of performance loss?" -- no; why would you think so?

Comment: @Jim. I jumped to conclusions so I refined my question a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are not making extensive use of large mmaps or the long long type the performance penalty will be a few percent at most, likely nothing significant at all. The 64 bit version will also likely be larger which could be a disadvantage anyway when considering the likelihood of causing memory paging on low resource systems. A few more registers will be available but in most programs this still has little impact on speed.

The instruction set will not be reduced as such, it will simply not use 64 bit mode of the CPU and thus not use the 64 bit extended versions of instructions.

Look here for more information on the performance implications:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit_computing#32-bit_vs_64-bit

Comment: From my own experience, recompiling 32-bit code as 64-bit has increased the performance about 10% without any other changes. I looked at the asm output and the benefit comes from the extra registers.

Comment: @BitBank Hmn, those are interesting findings, what kind of code was it? As I have found that some mathematical code does benefit significantly. Have you tried compiling said code with the X32 ABI, that will compile it for 32 bit without cutting out the full register set? It would allow you to check if it is purely those providing benefit.

Comment: For the vast majority of my code, I never depend on the compiler for high performance. Any time-critical sections I write in asm.